# Duplicate a receive location in Biztalk

Tags: biztalk, receive-location

I have a Biztalk application the requires about a dozen receive locations that are all almost exactly the same (one property, the folder on a remote FTP site, is different between them). Ideally, I'd like to take one location I've already created, and have Biztalk copy it a bunch of times, and I'll just edit the properties for each copy so it's correct.

Is there an easy way to duplicate an existing receive location, or do I have to create all dozen locations by hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just edit the binding file by hand.  Export the bindings of the application.  Copy the receive location block and paste it.  Modify the specifics. Reload the bindings into the application.

Comment: That actually looks like it's the closest to what I'm looking for. The password isn't exported, so I'd need to fix that by hand on each one, but it takes care of the rest of the settings. Thank you!

Comment: The password is an issue.  It won't put the password in the bindings file on export to protect it.  You generally build the bindings file for deployment, so it is maintained with passwords as an artifact in your project.  Another word of warning on the passwords in the bindings file... read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325892/biztalk-soap-port-password-in-binding-file.  It's SOAP specific but applies to the password field in other adapters.

Answer (score 0):

You could code it by using the Object Model or a WMI program.  Unfortunately, I know of know way to do it in the GUI.

Neal Walters

Comment: Fair enough. I was hoping there was even a SQL script that was in circulation out there that would let me do it in the database, but I haven't been able to find one. Thanks!